# How to scroll the webpages based on the hand gesture.hand motion

Tags: javascript, python

How to scroll the page up / down or left/right side by using the hand gesture using pyhton/javascript.
I tried lot to find the solution but not able figure out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the issue with your current code?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Hand Gesture Plugin (JSHG) is a wonderful plugin that allows you to support the hand gesture recognition of users through web camera in your existing websites or web applications. You do not need to have any background in computer vision to use this plugin. It currently offers the basic set of hand gestures which include the position of the hand (left, right, up, down) and counts the number of fingers. We provide a well-designed API for you to integrate JSHG to your application easily. If you have a strong background in computer vision, it is very simple for you to customize JSHG according to your preference.
https://nhudinhtuan.github.io/jshg/ refer too this link

Comment: Is there any better documentation about this plugin? I didn't find the documentation provided there really helpful.